# check the checkbox base on the response coming from axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a checkbox

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
       <input type="checkbox" value="add user" v-model="user.permissions">Add User
   </label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="edit user" v-model="user.permissions">
    Edit User
    </label>
</div>
```

the checkbox is v-model on user.permission array

```
user:{
    permissions: []
},
```

in which when i check a checkbox it will produce a result like this

```
user:Object
    permissions:Array[2]
        0:"edit user"
        1:"add user"
```

now when i fetch a data from my backend using axios and put the data on `user`

```
editUser: function(id){
    let vm = this;
    axios.get('api/users/' + id)
    .then( response => {
         vm.user = response.data.data; //PUT RESPONSE DATA TO USER OBJECT
         vm.usersModal = true;
        })
        .catch( error => {
         console.log(error);
        });
   },
```

it will produced an output like this

```
user:Object
    created_at:"2018-08-28 03:17:33"
    deleted_at:null
    email:"aa@gmail.com"
    id:3
    name:"aa"
    permissions:Array[2]
        0:Object
            created_at:"2018-08-28 03:03:41"
            guard_name:"web"
            id:2
            name:"delete user"
            pivot:Object
            updated_at:"2018-08-28 03:03:41"
        1:Object
            created_at:"2018-08-28 03:03:41"
            guard_name:"web"
            id:3
            name:"add user"
            pivot:Object
            updated_at:"2018-08-28 03:03:41"
      updated_at:"2018-08-28 03:17:33"
```

Now how can I check the checkbox using only v-model user.permission. I used the v-model user.permission because I'm using it on posting a request. However when I fetch it using id the data structure changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to modify the fetched response:

```
editUser: function(id){
    let vm = this;
    axios.get('api/users/' + id)
    .then( response => {
         response.data.data.user.permissions = response.data.data.user.permissions.map((item) =>
         {
           return item.name; // <--- convert the array of objects into array of strings
         });
         vm.user = response.data.data; //PUT RESPONSE DATA TO USER OBJECT
         vm.usersModal = true;
        })
        .catch( error => {
         console.log(error);
        });
   },
```